# Fetching value from multiple data set using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 A       B
101 BOX
101 CAB
101 DAD
101 FIBC
101 INT
102 BOX
102 CAB
102 DAD
102 INT
103 BOX
103 CAB
103 FIBC
103 INT
```

This is data in 2 columns A and B... If I supply 'BOX','CAB','DAD','INT','FIBC' then only 101 should be fetched using sql.. Need to use sql query pls suggest...

Comment: your question isn't clear, Please be more specific to get answers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A FROM TABLEX WHERE B IN ('BOX','CAB','DAD','INT','FIBC')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

5 being the number of variables listed, that is of course taking into consideration that you dont allow dupes.

If you allow dupes, you can always wrap it like this:

```
SELECT C.A FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM TABLEX WHERE B IN ('BOX','CAB','DAD','INT','FIBC')
) AS C
GROUP BY C.A
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

Comment: If you are passing values to the function, you can use something akin to a split function (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/031004-1.shtml) and then use the returning table to count the number of unique values and use that in the in clause to create the unique count and find the record that has all attributes.